# How to add a constraint where depending on your date of birth you can only borrow a certain number of books?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables: 
Book (sNo) 
Borrow (sNo, lNo) 
Person(lNo, name, dob)
Now here I need to add a constraint the if the loaner is a certain age, they can only get so many books.
I was thinking about something that counts the lNo where the name is the same and if it is already at the limit, they cannot loan another book. But I don't know how to do this. Is there any way to do it with only constraints and not triggers?

Comment: You *can* do it with constraints, but that requires UDFs.  For that effort, you might as well use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that is possible.

If you want a solution free from race conditions, you probably have to denormalize too: Add a `borrow_count` to the person with an appropriate check constraint. This number is maintained by triggers on `borrow`.